# Passing data from a map annotation to a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mkmapview

Currently, I have a map view that displays locations on a map. When the location annotation is selected on the map, it opens up a new view controller. How would I pass the name of the place displayed in the annotation on the map to the new view controller?

Here is a picture of the new view controller that opens up from the annotation.
[image]

Here is the code for the mapView.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

struct PlacesOnMap {
var name: String
var latitude: Double
var longitude: Double

init(name: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    self.name = name
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
}
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

var places = [PlacesOnMap(name: place 1), 
PlacesOnMap(name: place 2)
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

setupAnnotations()
}

func setupAnnotations() {
    let places = places.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
        let place = MKPointAnnotation()
        place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
        place.title = placeOnMap.name
        return place
    }
    mapView.addAnnotations(places)
}

extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    guard let annotationTitle = view.annotation?.title else { return }
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyCommunityStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    let destVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailMapItemsViewController") as! DetailMapItemsViewController
    destVC.placeNameText = annotationTitle!
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)
}
}
```

Here is what I have so far for my DetailViewController.

```
import UIKit

struct PlacesDetailView {
var name: String

init(name: String) {
self.name = name
}

class DetailMapItemsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nameOfPlaceLabel: UILabel!

var placeNameText: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    nameOfPlaceLabel?.text = placeNameText
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the data to the `DetailViewController` using the below code.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

struct PlacesOnMap {
    var name: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double

init(name: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    self.name = name
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView1: MKMapView!
    var places1 = [ PlacesOnMap(name: "Bangalore", latitude: 12.9716, longitude: 77.5946), PlacesOnMap(name: "Mysore", latitude: 12.2958, longitude: 76.6394)]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupAnnotations()
        mapView1.delegate = self
}

func setupAnnotations() {
    let places = places1.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
        let place = MKPointAnnotation()
        place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
        place.title = placeOnMap.name
        return place
    }
    mapView1.addAnnotations(places)
}
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
         guard let annotationTitle = view.annotation?.title else
               {
                   print("Unable to retrieve details")
                return
               }
      print("User tapped on annotation with title: \(annotationTitle!)")

        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let home = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
         home.placeNameText = annotationTitle!
        navigationController?.pushViewController(home, animated: true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've implemented this and when I run the app it works, but the placeNameText does not change. How would I fix this? My code is updated to match what I have.

Comment: It does change . Before pushing the view controller , you must assign the value of placeNameText, so that a new value will be assigned .

Comment: When I assign the the value of placeNameText I before pushing the viewController, var placeNameText = "", I get an alert that says Variable 'placeNameText' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it.

Comment: in the above code, let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let home = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
         home.placeNameText = annotationTitle! // Here I am passing the data to detailViewController.

Comment: So, annotationTitle will be passed to DetailViewController and displayed in the label in the view.

Comment: so If you have multiple locations with annotations as defined in the above answer, you will get corresponding values in this on clicking the annotation and the same will be sent to the DetailViewController.